# Creating an Object Based on a Function Arguement C++

Tags: c++, syntax, new-operator

Say I have a member function that creates a new object and places it into a data structure (in this case a map) in the class:

```
Class A
{
    std::map<std::pair<int,int>, BaseClass*> store;
    //...
    public:
    void createObject(?a?)
    {
        BaseClass* temp = new ?a?;
        //place in map...
    };
};
```

Where `?a?` is an argument that can be used to create an object that can be a number of different classes derived from `BaseClass`. The only way I can think of doing this is by making `?a?` an `int`, and manually typing each type into a switch statement.

Comment: What is your actual question? How to know which derived type to instantiate, or how to know which arguments to pass to the constructor, or..?

Comment: How to know which type to instantiate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a member function template. In the context of your example:

```
template<class T>
void createObject()
{
    BaseClass* temp = new T();
    //place in map...
};
```

Invoke with:

```
a.createObject<B>();
```

Where `a` is an instance of `A`, and `B` is a type derived from `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 2):

A template is a better solution than an enum because it doesn't require any maintenance. Any new subclasses will automatically be supported. Type safety between pointer types guarantees that T is a subclass of temp (otherwise the assignment will fail).

```
Class A
{
    std::map<std::pair<int,int>, BaseClass*> store;
    //...
    public:
    template <typename T>
    void createObject()
    {
        BaseClass* temp = new T();
        //place in map...
    };
};
```

The compiler cannot deduce the template type automagically without a dependant argument, so you'll need to qualify it.

```
Class Foo : public BaseClass { ... };

A a;
a.createObject<Foo>();
```

Comment: Its not that it can't deduce it, it that it doesn't have information to deduce it from.

Comment: @Dani: Clarified my statement a bit. If you have a suggested wording, I'll use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you know what kind of object to create.

If it is reasonable to base that on an int (eg a return code from some function) then a switch statement is fine. Note that you need to create each object with a call to new for it's type and then cast the object pointer to BaseClass to put into the map.

If you are passing in an object of the type then use a template.  edit: as Jon's answer

Answer (score 0):

You should make an enumeration of the possible classes that can be created and pass one to createObject function, for example:

```
enum FRUIT_CLASS { APPLE, ORANGE, BANANA };
...
void A::createObject( FRUIT_CLASS )
{ 
  switch(FRUIT_CLASS)
  // etc
}
```

This way, you are actually passing an integer as a parameter, but your code is more understandable, modifiable and maintainable.